# why the graph generated by def function is different from the normal block of codes (python)?

Tags: python, layout, charts

Could anyone look at the below codes and tell me WHY the two charts have the x-axis in a different format and HOW to adjust the codes in the **def function** to make two charts have an identical layout? The range is the same, just confused why they express in different ways. I am not able to post any image as a starter. Sorry for any inconvenience.

```
dtree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=id, criterion='gini')

tree_depth = np.arange(1, 16)
train_scores, test_scores = validation_curve(dtree, x_train, y_train,
                                             param_name='max_depth', param_range=tree_depth,
                                             scoring='accuracy', cv=5)
plt.figure()
train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
test_scores_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)

plt.plot(tree_depth, train_scores_mean, 'o-', color='red', label='training score')
plt.fill_between(tree_depth, train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,
                 train_scores_mean + train_scores_std, alpha=0.1, color='red')

plt.plot(tree_depth, test_scores_mean, 'o-', color='blue', label='validation score')
plt.fill_between(tree_depth, test_scores_mean - test_scores_std,
                 test_scores_mean + test_scores_std, alpha=0.1, color='blue')

plt.title('Validation Curve: Decision Tree for Cancer')
plt.xlabel('tree_depth')
plt.ylabel('accuracy score')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.grid()
```

The xlim shows like [2 4 6 8 10 12 14]

```
def validationcurve(interval, estimator, x, y, parameter, title):
    train_scores, test_scores = validation_curve(estimator, x, y, param_name=parameter, param_range=interval, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=4, cv=5)

    plt.figure()
    train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)

    plt.semilogx(interval, train_scores_mean, 'o-', color='r', label='Training score')
    plt.fill_between(interval, train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,
                     train_scores_mean + train_scores_std, alpha=0.1, color='r')
    plt.semilogx(interval, test_scores_mean, 'o-', color='b', label='Validation score')
    plt.fill_between(interval, test_scores_mean - test_scores_std,
                     test_scores_mean + test_scores_std, alpha=0.1, color='b')

    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel(parameter)
    plt.ylabel("Score")
    plt.legend(loc="best")
    plt.grid()
    plt.savefig(fig_path + title+'.png')
    plt.clf()

validationcurve(np.arange(1, 16), dtree, x_train, y_train, parameter='max_depth', title='dtree_validation_curve_max_depth')
```

The xlim shows like [10^0, 10^1]

Comment: `range` is a builtin function in `python`, so you shouldn't use it as a variable name. I don't know if this is related, but it makes the code very fragile and hard to follow.

Comment: but even I change the 'range' to any other names, the format of the x-axis generated by the def function is still like [10^0, 10^1], if I want the format shows exactly like [2, 4,...14], how should I update the def function?

Comment: Can you change `range` in the example code in your question? It might help get an answer if it is easier to read.